# Своя кнопка закрытия окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать кнопку закрытия окна нестандартного размера 16х16 средствами tkinter?
Иконка - крестик(символ), чтобы не было лишних файлов, при наведении на кнопку крестик меняет цвет.
Без рамок, цвет фона неизменный.

Пробовал:
tk.Button - не получилось убрать отступы текста
ttk.Button - нет параметра height
tk.Label - нет параметра height

Пример кода:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTH, RAISED, N, E, S, W, X, Y

root = tk.Tk()

mw = tk.Frame(root, background='red', width=100, height=100)
tl = tk.Label(mw, text='Test', fg="#333333", bg="#CCCCCC", font = "Courier 16 bold", bd=0)
tl.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
mw.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

root.configure(highlightthickness=5, highlightcolor='green')
root.mainloop()
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема:
Сверху и снизу есть отступы около 4 пикселей, хотя слева и справа от текста отступ порядка 1 пикселя.

### Можно ли отредактировать label таким образом?

(только не для всех label, а для одного)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()

fr = ttk.Frame(root).pack()

mb = ttk.Menubutton(fr, text='fegvd').pack()

style.layout("TMenubutton", [
   ("Menubutton.background", None),
   ("Menubutton.button", {"children":
       [("Menubutton.focus", {"children":
           [("Menubutton.padding", {"children":
               [("Menubutton.label", {"side": "left", "expand": 1})]
           })]
       })]
   }),
])

root.mainloop()
```

Например как-то так:

```
style.layout("tl.TLabel": {"pady": "0"})
```

Comment: Label положить во Frame, для Frame задать нужные размеры

Comment: для label же нужно тоже размер указывать...?

Comment: Если для label нельзя указать высоту, то в любом случае можно через pack или grid указать, чтобы label расширился на весь фрейм, а для фрейма указать высоту можно.

Comment: Кстати, с чего вы взяли, что Label нет параметра height? Он есть, просто он задает высоту в символах.

Comment: insolor, как я понимаю высоту label можно изменить размером высоты текста находящимся в нем, но при размере 16 пикселей текст становится нечитаемым, можно ли убрать отступы в самом label? я использую bd=0 для label, но этого все равно не достаточно.... Вертикальная составляющая все равно с отступом.

Comment: Добавьте пример кода в вопрос, и опишите конкретные проблемы, которые у вас возникли.

Comment: insolor, добавил.

Comment: Напрямую через label скорее всего эти отступы убрать не получится. Вот тут есть вариант через Canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481915/4752653. Если нужен просто крестик (для кнопки закрытия окна), я бы просто картинку 16x16 вставил.

Comment: insolor, необходимо чтобы все данные были в самом файле. Exe создавать не хочется. Можно ли png картинку запихнуть в py/pyw файл? Можно svg файл, но если не ошибаюсь нужны библиотеки для работы с svg форматом, а мне нужно чтобы без сторонних библиотек. Походу canvas единственный оставшийся вариант.

Comment: Тогда можно Canvas, на нем нарисовать крест линиями

Comment: insolor, а если кнопку настроек надо будет? тоже рисовать?

Comment: insolor, добавил еще вопрос.

Comment: То что вы называете отступом - это не отступ, это фактически часть текста для всяких "хвостиков" и диакритических (надстрочных/подстрочных) знаков выше и ниже буквы. padding добавляется уже дополнительно, поэтому убирание паддинга никак не влияет. Если не рисовать линиями, то рисовать текст на Canvas, и принудительно обрезать "лишние" (с вашей точки зрения) части, как в ответе, ссылку на который я дал выше в комментариях.

Answer (score 1):

При изменении размера шрифта меняется и размеры отступа по вертикали и горизонтали, в связи с этим сделал на шрифт 12 размера отступы = 0, при изменении размера шрифта можно откорректировать размеры отступов за счет параметров padx и pady, которые могут принимать и отрицательные значения.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class MLabel():
    def __init__(self, parent, text='Text', fill='black', font=('Calibri', 12), ratio=2/7, bg='#F2F2F2', padx=0, pady=0):
        self.parent = parent
        self.text = text
        self.fill = fill
        self.font = font
        self.ratio = ratio
        self.bg = bg
        self.padx = padx
        self.pady = pady

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.parent, bg=self.bg, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.txtid = self.canvas.create_text(self.padx, self.pady-5, text=self.text, fill=self.fill, font=self.font, anchor='nw')
        self.bbox = self.canvas.bbox(self.txtid)
        self.canvas.configure(width=self.bbox[2]+2*self.padx, height=self.bbox[3]+self.pady-4)

label = MLabel(root, text='X',font=('Calibri', 16, 'bold'), padx=1, pady=-1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Результат:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class MLabel():
    def __init__(self, parent, text='Text', fill='black', font=('Calibri', 16), ratio=2/7, bg='#F2F2F2'):
        self.parent = parent
        self.text = text
        self.fill = fill
        self.font = font
        self.ratio = ratio
        self.bg = bg

        self.pady=int(self.font[1]*self.ratio)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.parent, bg=self.bg)
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.txtid = self.canvas.create_text(0, -self.pady, text=self.text, fill=self.fill, font=self.font, anchor='nw')
        self.bbox = self.canvas.bbox(self.txtid)
        self.canvas.configure(width=self.bbox[2], height=self.bbox[3]-self.pady)

label = MLabel(root, font=('Calibri', 50))

root.mainloop()
```

P.S. Если есть советы как улучшить, пишите.
И еще вопрос, каким образом сделать grid() после label = ?

Comment: insolor, каким образом сделать grid() после label = ?

Comment: Ну, у вас при создании MLabel внутренний canvas сам размещается через grid, поэтому как бы дополнительно MLabel размещать через grid не нужно. Можно переделать, чтобы MLabel наследовался от Canvas, тогда его можно будет размещать вызовом метода grid "снаружи" объекта. Как-то так: https://pastebin.com/dNh6q9qm

Comment: insolor, заметил еще одну проблему, на маленьких размерах деление отступов происходит неравномерно.

Comment: можно ли сконфигурировать позицию create_text снова?

Comment: Там еще нужно убрать границу canvas: `super().__init__(parent, *args, bg=bg, highlightthickness=0, **kwargs)`, и похоже на 1 уменьшить итоговые размеры: `self.configure(width=bbox[2]-1, height=bbox[3]-pady-1)`

Comment: Позицию текста можно менять с помощью метода moveto: `self.moveto(self.txtid, x=..., y=...)` или через имя объекта вместо self, если не из метода вызывать.